# Are there any alternatives to IL offsets to get more context in a stack trace in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, debugging, exception, stack-trace

I understand the decision not to include PDB's in a XAP file. This of course means no line numbers in an exception stack trace. [Others have looked for this](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/131601/300964.aspx#300964), and [we can get IL offsets to hunt things down](http://liviutrifoi.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/silverlight-stack-trace-line-numbers/).

That's fine and all, but the build/run/test/debug cycle for SL already seems a bit slow, and I'd rather not have to add disassemble with Reflector or ildasm to this overhead. Are there any alternatives?

For example, is it possible to inject the PDB's? I'm willing to bet any support for that is stripped from the SL CLR. Is there a tool that exists that maps IL back to line numbers? I'm willing to bet no there too, though I have ideas on how to create one.

Comment: What is the problem? You have the XAP file, you open it and ILDASM the offending file AFTER someone tells you of the bug

Comment: Not a problem per se, just yet another thing to do. But ya, comes with the territory :)

Comment: My point is that you can do it "post mortem". You don't need to do it pre-emtpively. I know, you would prefer to have the row number directly in the log file. And perhaps even the solution to the bug :-)

Comment: Now that would be awesome, but then, oh shoot no job.

Comment: I'd be happy if I could even get ILOffsets working - at least there is a *way* if it is working. But in my experience, and others have confirmed, this only works for silverlight assemblies compiled in debug mode, not release. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264543/il-offsets-missing-when-silverlight-assembly-is-compiled-in-release-mode